# Winforms C# VerticalScroll Bar on DataGridview not displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My windows form application ,I  have a gridview on my application and displays all the data required.

Problem is the vertical scrollbar is not visible, but when you scroll your mouse up and down it works.

Any specific property that I need to check?

Please note the scrollbar property's value is already  set to BOTH screenshot below:

[image: property]

the gridview columns are also set / defined manually and not auto generated, autogeneratecolumn is false

this is my application screenshot below:

[image: application]

Comment: how is the width of the columns determined? what happens when you scroll completely to the right with the horizontal scrollbar ?

Comment: Width of the columns are pre-defined based on the requirement given to me. @MongZhu

Comment: I can see the vertical scroll bar.  It is light gray and background is dark gray.  Scroll bar would be easier to see if you changed the color.

Comment: How do you fill the grid? Any `Invoke` calls? Call `.PerformLayout();` or set the `ScrollBars` property after filling the grid and try.

Comment: @dr.null no invoke calls , just normal filling (datagridview.datasource). I'm also calling peformLayout method after filling the grid view

Comment: @jdweng that's not scrollbar , that's empty space

Comment: In the black box there is a scrollbar.  In the application it looks like a website I use that a very thin scrollbar.  Try making border wider.

Comment: I don't know. In this case, I'd backup my app, set the grid's properties to the default values (especially the rows and columns size modes), set them back one by one until I catch the problem. Give it a try. Adding new clean Form and handling the grid view only is another way.

Answer (score 1):

Update , the solution to my problem is remove the filling of gridview on Background Worker.

Since I was using background worker for this operation , tried removing it and the scrollbars also displayed.

Another thing that I found out when you have background color on column headers by default the scrollbars will not show if datagridview.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false.

The Work around that I tried and actually works  is to set these properties to true:

dataGridView1.Controls[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVC9z.png).Enabled = true; // Index one is the vertical scrollbar
dataGridView1.Controls[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVC9z.png).Visible = true; // Index one is the vertical scrollbar

[image: Solution]